# GUI to BROWSE network without specifying remote servers

Tags: networking, gui, cifs, client

Its 2018, I'm using Kubuntu 18.1 cosmic, looking for a GUI to BROWSE network (CIFS) shares on other machines.
I'm running a linux desktop machine, (not a server) and don't want to run, or install a samba server.
I am told that I don't need to run a samba server in order to access shares on another machine.
The problem that I have is browsing the network from LINUX machines.
Programs that I find require you to identify the remote server, I'm looking for something like network neighbourhood, which can find shares on other machines that I don't specify.